# Can you explain this x86-64 Assembly program

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I am currently learning some x86 Assembly and I would like if someone could explain what this program is doing. I know that it is a "Hello World" program, but I don't understand how it is doing it, or what any code means.

```
.data
.globl greet
greet:
.string "Hello world."

.text
.global main
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp,       %rbp
    movq    $greet,     %rdi
    call    puts
    movq    $0,         %rax
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info for the syntax basics, and https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ for the GAS directives.  Looks like clumsy hand-written code for x86-64 Linux for a traditional non-PIE executable; it won't link as a PIE because it [uses a 32-bit absolute address for `greet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register).  (And I say "clumsy" because `main` returns `int`, not `long`, so there's no point in using `movq`)

Comment: This wouldn't work on MacOS because of the 32-bit absolute address, and wouldn't work on Windows because Windows uses a different calling convention.  It might work on some BSD versions, IDK, but it's probably easiest to call it a Linux example.  (And then only for non-PIE executables; building this with `gcc foo.S` on a modern distro where PIE is the default would also choke on `puts` instead of `call puts@plt` or gcc -fno-plt style `call *puts@GOTPCREL(%rip)`, as well as the 32-bit absolute address)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `.data` this the place were you put headers and defines to use in main:
- `.global greet` .global means the label will be the visible to the linker because in main we will use it.
- `greet:` the label initializing
- `pushq   %rbp`: push rbp register onto the stack
- `movq    %rsp, %rbp`:  RBP = RSP
- `movq $greet, %rdi`:  RDI = address of `greet` label
- `call puts`: api to print string, which looks for a pointer in RDI
- `movq $0, %rax`: nop rax(clear data)
- `leave`: exit label
- `ret`: termination

Comment: There is no `greet` function here, that label is on data.  The function-call is to `puts`, passing the address of the global `char greet[] = "...";`

Comment: `greet:` will be visible within the same file even without `.globl`.  Just `greet:` alone is like `static char greet[]` in C.  Using `.globl` makes it like a C global var (still in static storage-class, but without the file-scope visibility limit).

Comment: Also, terminology nitpick: generally avoid the word "storing" when not writing memory.  *load* the address of `greet` into RDI.  (And it's not loading the data, that's the point of the `$`.)

Comment: In `movq    %rsp, %rbp`, RBP is the *destination*.  I fixed that for you.  Also, `leave` doesn't "exit" from a label, it's an instruction (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/leave).  Exactly equivalent to `mov %rbp, %rsp` ; `pop %rbp`.  Also, `ret` isn't "termination", it pops a return address into RIP, returning control to the CRT startup code that called main.

Comment: Also `mov $0, %rax` isn't a NOP, it sets RAX = 0.  Main's caller will look for the `int main` return address in EAX, and pass that to the libc `exit()` function.  This answer also misses explaining *why* the code messes around with RBP at all (traditional frame pointer, which works as a way tore-align the stack by 16 before a function call.)

Answer (score 0):

**I do not program in Assembly** but I'll try:

- <del>`.data`: Declare new RAM address.</del> .data means .section .data, which switches to the .data section. (Thanks Peter Cordes for pointing this out!)
- `.globl greet`: Sets the variable `greet` to global visibility.
- `greet`: declares greet.
- `.string "Hello World"` sets it to Hello World.
- the rest of the code prints it out.

Comment: `.data` doesn't really "declare a new RAM address".  It sets the assembler's current section to `.data`, i.e. a shortcut for `.section .data`.  Just like `.text` switches (back) to the `.text` section, so later lines will assemble bytes into that section.  (It's up to the linker to map sections to absolute addresses, when linking this into a non-PIE executable.)  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Data.html

Comment: Also, `.globl greet` doesn't *declare* anything; it sets the visibility attribute for `greet` *if* this source file happens to define that symbol on another line before or after.  (Which it does with a `greet:` label).  If there had been no `greet:`, then `.globl greet` would have absolutely no effect.